# raise Exception not catching exception as expected with two functions

Tags: python, exception, raiserror

Here is the Code :

```py
def funcFail():
    try:
        raise Exception("Failed externally")
        print("Should not print")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception : {e}")
        raise Exception(f"Exception in occured due: {e}")
    finally:
        return "This is finally block :P"
        print("This is finally block :P")

def checkexpcep():
    global k 
    k = []
    try:
        funcFail()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception out : {e}")
        k.append(str(e))
    finally:
        return "nothing"

checkexpcep()
```

**Expected :**

```
"Exception : Failed externally"
"This is finally block :P"
"Exception out : Exception in occured due: Failed externally"
```

**Output :**

```
"Exception : Failed externally"
```

Comment: Apparently the `return` in `finally` [swallows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808107/should-return-outside-finally-and-is-the-exception-handled-perfectly) the exception.

Comment: @quamrana, is there any alternative or should i proceed without finally?

Comment: I'd also advise using a custom exceptions, might make code like this easier to debug: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions

Comment: You should use `finally` in order to tidy up whether there is an exception or not. Only use `return <something>` when you want to return something when there is no exception, So it seems `return` is out of place in `finally`.

Answer (score 0):

next time try to use python debugger (any ide is good enough, pycharm or wing,..etc). anyway see my inline comment numbers in your code below:

```
def funcFail():
    try:
        # (2)
        raise Exception("Failed externally")
        print("Should not print")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception : {e}")
        # (3)
        raise Exception(f"Exception in occured due: {e}")   
    finally:
        # (4)
        return "This is finally block :P"
        print("This is finally block :P")

def checkexpcep():
    global k 
    k = []
    try:
        # (1)
        funcFail()
        # (5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception out : {e}")
        k.append(str(e))
    finally:
        return "nothing"

checkexpcep()
```

after calling `checkexpcep()` you reach point `1` in the code. then you call `funcFail()` and reach point `2`, at `2` you are raising an exception which cactched by the except block and you reach point `3` with this exception, after printing the exception, you are raising new exception at point `3`, and you reach the `finally`  block and python execute it (be aware, finally always executed). you are returning from finally block with the string `"This is finally block :P"`.this shallow or hides the previous exception. the return brings you to point `5`. nothing is done with the return value and the program is finished succefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want your expected output, then just move the `return` out of the `finally` block:

```py
def funcFail():
    try:
        raise Exception("Failed externally")
        print("Should not print")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception : {e}")
        raise Exception(f"Exception in occurred due: {e}")
    finally:
        print("This is finally block :P")
    return "This is finally block :P"

def checkexpcep():
    global k 
    k = []
    try:
        funcFail()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception out : {e}")
        k.append(str(e))
    finally:
        return k,"nothing"

print(checkexpcep())
```

Output:

```
Exception : Failed externally
This is finally block :P
Exception out : Exception in occurred due: Failed externally
(['Exception in occurred due: Failed externally'], 'nothing')
```

(Note I added the print of a `tuple` at the end to show the value of `k`)